# background gradient is removed when using float attribute in css

Tags: html, css

**when using float attribute on div tag, the gradient set as background is removed. The last css property i.e the float attribute in the div.image removes the background.**

here is the HTML code

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="info">
            <h2>Enter details</h2>
            <h3>Username</h3>
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <h3>Password</h3>
            <input type="text" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="image"><img class="image" src="C:\Users\Desktop\New folder\Picture\light-trails-8.jpg"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is the css code

```
div.content{
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#0080ff 50% , lightblue);
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    }

img.image{
    width:250px;
    height: 250px;
}

div.info{
    float:left;
}
/***** After applying this style ****/
div.image{
    float:right;
}
```

here is the screenshot of designed webpage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oczjn.png)

Comment: You simply can add width:100% in your content class. it should solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children inside `div.content` are float. Add this to fix:

```
div.content {
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#0080ff 50% , lightblue);
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top: 3px;

    /*  Add this */
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```